# Creating an edge between two vertexes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to model a bar front, but I'm having problems extruding the right part of the face.

I keep trying to add a vertex between two points of a sized up cube object but it isn't allowing me to connect the two, giving me the error `invalid selection`.

Any ideas on how I can do it please?

Its the triangle shape I'm trying to get

[image: vertex issue]

Bar front I'm trying to model

[image: bar front im trying to model]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make smart use of modifiers here. You have a repeating shape, use an *Array* modifier instead of modelling it all one by one by hand.

For the face keep it simple. Just use the *Poke Faces* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> operator on a simple unsubdivided face.

Move the resulting vertex down to vertically align with the bottom vertex of the face, then move it forward to make the protruding "pyramid" shape.

[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't realize blender had this! How did you use the array modifiers to dupe the shape?  Edit: Nm found out how, thank you Duarte!

Answer (score 2):

Duarte's answer is perfect, for this case.

In general, if you were trying to create a vertex on an edge by connecting, (`J`), that won't work. In this context, `J` connects existing vertices across existing faces. Alternatives include:

`Ctrl-E` (Edge Menu) > Subdivide, with the edge/s on which you want the vertices to appear selected.

Select a vertex on the edge you want divided, duplicate it with `Alt-D` and slide it along the edge (`GG`).

If your new vertex is going to be at the end of a new edge in an existing face, the Knife tool (`K`) from the beginning of the new edge, using `Ctrl` if necessary, to constrain the cuts to the center of existing edges.